# Multiple If Functions

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help for my code. I want to copy client's name on column C based on these 2 conditions if:

1. Macro find value = "ongoing" on Column G
2. Macro find value = "Istry" on column D

In other words if macro find "ongoing" and "istry" at same row, it will copy automatically the client's name associated with these 2 values asked on another sheet.

I wrote a code but when I tried to run it, I didn't get any result on my sheet.

```
Sub Ss()

Dim finalrow As Long, i As Long, rowpt As Long, colpt As Long

    finalrow = ShSReturn.Range("D" & "G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    rowpt = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colpt = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    Call Entry_Point

    For i = 7 To finalrow
        If ShSReturn.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Istry" & ShSReturn.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Ongoing" Then
            ShSReturn.Cells(i, 3).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(rowpt + 6, 12).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            rowpt = rowpt + 1
            colpt = colpt + 1

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: try changing `&` for `and` in your `if` statement

Comment: `&` is a string operator it concatenates what is before and what is after so in the end vba is trying to equate `IstryTrue` or `IstryFalse`, depending on the outcome of `ShSReturn.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Ongoing"`, to `ShSReturn.Cells(i, 4).Value`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I tried but same as before, no result

Comment: @ScottCraner I rewrite my code as you suggest and  If ShSReturn.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Istry", to ShSReturn.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Ongoing" Then, this line become "red"

Comment: That suggests that your `finalRow` is not being set correct. `ShSReturn.Range("D" & "G" & Rows.Count)....` is looking at the row count of column `DG` not both `D` and `G `seperately. Perhaps just pick one of the two columns: `ShSReturn.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row()` and rerun.

Comment: @JNevill I want to loop on 2 columns and don't want to set a "range". Can somebody give me an advice to rewrite my variables?

Comment: What does "Loop on 2 columns mean" that is not a thing that can happen. It sounds like you want to loop through all rows in you worksheet where columns D OR G are populated. Is that right? In that case you'll need to determine the last row for BOTH `D` and `G` columns then figure out which one is bigger and use that bigger value in your `For` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions here about your intent for this code here is a quick rewrite:

```
Sub Ss()

    Dim finalrow As Long, i As Long, rowpt As Long, colpt As Long

    'Determine how many rows we need to loop:
    finalDRow = ShSReturn.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    finalGRow = ShSReturn.RAnge("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop only through rows were both G and D have records
    If finalDRow < finalGRow Then finalrow = finalDRow Else finalRow = finalGRow


    'I don't know what these two are doing, but they will return the same exact number (the last row populated in column A of whatever worksheet object is in ShPPT
    rowpt = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    colpt = ShPPT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    Call Entry_Point

    'Loop through rows 7 to whatever finalRow shakes out to be above
    For i = 7 To finalrow
        'If column D is "Istry" AND column G is "Ongoing" Then execute this code.
        If ShSReturn.Cells(i, 4).Value = "Istry" AND ShSReturn.Cells(i, 7).Value = "Ongoing" Then
            ShSReturn.Cells(i, 3).Copy
            ShPPT.Cells(rowpt + 6, 12).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            rowpt = rowpt + 1
            colpt = colpt + 1

        End If  

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You can loop through to the last row of (say) column `D`. If it's the shorter one, the blank cells after the last row cannot have values of "ongoing" and don't need to be copied so no problem. If it's the longer one, then again, no problem

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That's a fine thought. I've updated the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Filter.

Be sure to set the appropriate worksheet references.

As written, the code copies the entire row, but you can easily modify it if you only want a few fields to be copied over.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Sub filterName()
    Const strG = "ongoing"
    Const strD = "lstry"
    Dim rCopyTo As Range
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet6")
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set rData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol))
End With

Set rCopyTo = Worksheets("sheet7").Cells(1, 1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
rData.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=strD, visibledropdown:=False
rData.AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:=strG, visibledropdown:=False

rCopyTo.Cells.Clear
rData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy rCopyTo
rData.Worksheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```